# Override bloks and models in Magento 1.9.4.0 is not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to override the function _prepareCollection in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid class

```
    <?php
class Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid
{
     protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
         echo "testing if overridden ";
        $allowProductTypes = array();
        foreach (Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration')->getConfigurableAllowedTypes() as $type) {
            $allowProductTypes[] = $type->getName();
        }

        $product = $this->_getProduct();
        $collection = $product->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$product->getAttributeSetId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('type_id', $allowProductTypes)
           // ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->joinAttribute('name', 'catalog_product/name', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->addCatalogInventoryToProductCollection($collection);
        }

        foreach ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProductAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attribute->getAttributeCode());
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array('notnull'=>1));
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        if ($this->isReadonly()) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $this->_getSelectedProducts()));
        }

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

in my config.xml I have this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <requiredoptions>
                <class>Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions_Helper</class>
            </requiredoptions>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <requiredoptions>
                <class>Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions_Block</class>
            </requiredoptions>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config_grid>Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid</catalog_product_edit_tab_super_config_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <requiredoptions>
                <class>Ayasoftware_RequiredOptions_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>requiredoptions_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </requiredoptions>

        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

the function _prepareCollection is overridden correctly, but still using the original function that does not filter by ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()

any idea how to fix this?
was working fine in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in creation collection and setting it again when you calling `parent::_prepareCollection()` before return statement. During that you executes `_prepareCollection` from parent class, in your case that parent will be : `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config_Grid`

But, you also need functionality which present in the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` class's `_prepareCollection` method.

so, to add rewrite and also to keep functionality from needed method just remove

```
parent::_prepareCollection();
return $this;
```

lines with next line

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
```

In your class's _prepareCollection method (after all your new lines)

Comment: if I remove // parent::_prepareCollection(); The configurable associated products are not pre-selected.

Comment: @MageDevBrossard, I added updates to my answer, please try that

Comment: Still not working. 
to reproduce the issue, create a simple product with a required custom option, and link it to a configurable product (as associated product). This simple product will be hidden in the the associated products tab. 
Magento is still looking for the function addFilterByRequiredOptions in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection class
public function addFilterByRequiredOptions()
    {
        $this->addAttributeToFilter('required_options', array(array('neq' => '1'), array('null' => true)), 'left');
        return $this;
    }